# Problem creating table with dynamic rows and columns using reportlab

Tags: reportlab

I am creating dynamic code for rows and columns using reportlab so that the user can give info for rows and columns through inputs. Now my problem is I created dynamic column headings successfully but the rows are not splitting according to the number of columns. They are printed on pdf as a line without splitting according to column headings. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
from reportlab.lib import colors

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

import os

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("teda.pdf", pagesize=letter)

# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []

# These are the column widths for the headings on the table
m = int(input("enter the number of column headings: "))

row_array = []

for i in range(0,m):

    columnHeading = input("enter col heading")
    row_array.append(columnHeading)
    tableHeading = [row_array]
    tH = Table(tableHeading)          
elements.append(tH)


#generating rows for each column

n = int(input("enter the number of rows: "))

row_array = []

# Assemble rows of data for each column

for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,n):
        columnData = str(input("enter col data"))
        row_array.append(columnData)
        tableRow = [row_array]
        tR=Table(tableRow)
elements.append(tR)

doc.build(elements)

print("writing")

xx = "teda.pdf"
os.startfile(xx)
```

I expect the results like:

```
TOM   CHRIST JERRY VIRAT  MARK
2300  435.5   398  2145  543.34
21      32    20    19    26       AND SO ON....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
for i in range(0,m):

    columnHeading = input("enter col heading")
    row_array.append(columnHeading)
    tableHeading = [row_array]
    tH = Table(tableHeading)
```

to

```
for i in range(0,m):
    columnHeading = input("enter col heading")
    row_array.append([columnHeading]) # Note [ ]
tH = Table(row_array)
```